# Rotate one row with column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following problem: I have one row of data, and I would like to rotate it with then names of the colums.

```
Collnames:     a    b   c    d
               0   NULL 1    0
```

And i woluld like to have The folowing:

```
Collnames  Data
a          0
b          Null
c          1
d          0
```

I made a solution for this, but its using dynamic SQL with a cursor, and I'm not proud of it. Is there a more elegat way to solve this problem?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an `UNPIVOT` though the built in operator won't preserve `b` as the value is `NULL` so you can do it this way.

```
SELECT ColNames,Data 
FROM   YourTable 
       CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ('a', a), 
                            ('b', b), 
                            ('c', c), 
                            ('d', d)) V(ColNames, Data)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4dee/5)